# Fast row deletion in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, row

I am working with a big numpy matrix (approximately 75k rows of 2 integers each) from which I have to delete some rows. I would like to know if there is a fast way to delete a row without regenerating the whole array i.e. is there a function the change just the "mask" (or whatever is called) of the matrix, without effectively delete the row in memory? I could then regenerate a clean matrix after I delete all the proper rows.

Comment: It seems like you want a view of an array with an irregular mask.  This isn't possible in `numpy` - if you don't use "fancy indexing" (i.e. extracting a regular "every i elements between j and k on axis l") you will always end up with your masked array being a reduced copy of the original - which is what I think you mean by "regenerating the whole array"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fast way to select rows from an array is with a slice, which produces a `view`.  But that requires a regular pattern like 'every-nth' row.  Any other select produces a copy.

```
x[::10,:]   # view
x[[1,3,6,10,20],:]   # copy
x[[True,False,False,True,False,...],:]   # copy
```

`np.delete` lets you specify which rows to remove, but it ends up, one or other, making a copy that contains the remaining rows.  It's a complex function using different methods depending on what you specify.  But in many cases it constructs a mask as @jakevdp demonstrates.

So the fastest way  to delete a bunch of rows is to delete them (or select their complement) all at once.  Deleting one at a time is the slow way.

Answer (score 5):

Although [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.html) are a thing, I would probably do this with a separate boolean mask, e.g.

```
big_array = np.random.rand(75000, 2)

rows_to_delete = np.random.randint(0, 75000, 500)
mask = np.ones(75000, dtype=bool)
mask[rows_to_delete] = False

output = big_array[mask]
print(output.shape)
# (74503, 2)
```

If you just have a list of indices to delete, the [`np.delete`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) function is also an option:

```
output = np.delete(big_array, rows_to_delete, axis=0)
print(output.shape)
# (74503, 2)
```

Note that in either of these options, it is a new array that is returned, not a view of the original array.